# Getting Device from ID3D11DeviceChild::GetDevice() method

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm trying to return the ID3D11Device object in my application using this method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicechild-getdevice

More specifically I'm using a returned Vertex Buffer to try and get the device like below:

```
pContext->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &veBuffer, &Stride, &veBufferOffset);
if (veBuffer)
    veBuffer->GetDesc(&vedesc);

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = vedesc.ByteWidth;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Device **pDeviceExtra = nullptr;
veBuffer->GetDevice(pDeviceExtra); //Can I use this to get to the device object?

//Create the buffer.
HRESULT hr = pDeviceExtra->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, NULL, &readVB);
assert(hr == S_OK);

pContext->CopyResource(readVB, veBuffer);
```

I'd like to create a buffer resource, however what happens is, when I try and use the returned device pointer, it says **"Expression must have a pointer to class type."** Now I did some research on this, and from what I gather you have to dereference the pointer to the object itself. in this case however, I'm not sure how to do that? I have created a device in my DirectX code, but for different reasons I'd like to get the device from the vertex buffer if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ID3D11Device *device = nullptr;
veBuffer->GetDevice(&device);

// Call device method

device->Release();
```

Notes:

- You should be passing the device pointer around to code that might want to create resources, or creating a singleton to your device abstraction so you can call it from anywhere, rather than using hacks like this.
- Use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` rather than raw pointers to manage the reference counts.